# Constraints on calling base constructor

Tags: c#

Let's say I have the following setup :

```
public abstract class A
{
    B b_ {get; set;} // where B is some abstract class

    public A(B b)
    {
        b_ = b;
    }
}

public class D : A
{
    // some new fields
    D(B b) : base(b)
    {

    }
}
```

where `B` is some abstract class from which derives various "concrete" types.

In `D`'s constructor I would like to put constraints on `b`'s runtime type, like allowing only certains type. To do this, I can remove the call to the base's constructor, check in `D`'s constructor for allowed "concrete" types *and* implement a default constructor in base class. Is there another way to do this ? (I find it also ugly to use base constructor and check after.)

Comment: I will edit the question

Comment: Sorry, deleted my comment, as I laster saw only the inline comment about B being abstract. You can Actually just call the base with any object, that derives from B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution could be to declare only constructors for allowed types.
Let's say you have these classes derived from `B`:

```
public class DeriveFromB1 : B {}
public class DeriveFromB2 : B {}
```

Then you could add two constructors to `D`:

```
public class D : A
{
    D(DerivedFromB1 b) : base(b)
    {
    }
    D(DerivedFromB2 b) : base(b)
    {
    }
}
```

Now `D` can only be constructed with arguments of these two types.

---

A second possibility is to make the constructor `private` or `protected` and provide `static` factory methods:

```
public class D : A
{
    private D(B b) : base(b)
    {
    }

    public static D Get(DerivedFromB1 b) => new D(b);
    public static D Get(DerivedFromB2 b) => new D(b);
}
```

In both cases you will have to implement methods for each type. If all relevant types inherit from the same `B`-derived class, you'd only need a method for that type.

Comment: Much cleaner than a runtime type check, although if there are many they may have to start looking for ways to generate the constructors.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Why is it cleaner than a runtime type check ?

Comment: Because the compiler *enforces* it at compile time. You're prevented from writing *wrong code* in the first place, rather than having to test it to locate the mistake.

Comment: @11house c# is a strongly typed language, so it's cleaner to use compile-time type checking where possible. The problem with run-time checking is: 1) what are you going to do when the type is wrong? 2) it's more expensive to detect a wrong usage of your class at run-time than avoiding mistakes at compile-time

Comment: @RenéVogt I think I prefer the first solution because it encompasses the immediate checking by restricting the allowed type.